# Looking to make sticky footer, remove white space

Tags: html, css

## Problem

a) On bigger screens there is white space below my footer that doesn't appear to be due to margin or padding, I'm wondering how to make it so regardless of screen size the footer will always hug the bottom of the screen, but will also not hide any text behind it.

b) There is white space on the right side of the screen that also doesn't seem to be a padding or margin, been trying to figure out what it is, haven't been able to identify it in the dev tools.

### Github repo: https://github.com/onlyandrewn/legislature

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Legislature App | Brandon Sun</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Brandon Sun's new leglislature app.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/icons/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="assets/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/icons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest" href="assets/img/icons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="assets/img/icons/mstile-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Roboto+Slab:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- Introduction to the legislature app -->
        <section class="intro clearfix">
            <div class="thin">
            </div><!-- /.thin -->
            <h1>How well are you represented in the Manitoba legislature?</h1>
            <p class="teaser">With Manitobans heading to the polls in 2016, now is your chance to discover how many members of the legislature actually represent you. With a highlighted racial divide in the province, diversity among representatives is more important now than ever. <a href="#selection"><strong>Select the categories below to find yourself in the new Manitoba legislature.</strong></a></p>
        </section>

        <!-- Three options readers can click -->
        <section class="interactive clearfix">
            <section class="selection" id="selection">
                <div class="gender">
                    <p class="category">Gender</p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <input type="radio" id="Male" class="button rect G1" name="gender"></input>
                        <label for="Male">Male</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="Female" class="button rect G1" name="gender"></input>
                        <label for="Female">Female</label>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.gender -->

                <div>
                    <p class="category">Age</p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <input class="age" type="radio" id="a35" class="button rect A1" name="age" value="35"></input>
                        <label for="a35">Under 35</label>

                        <input class="age" type="radio" id="a36" class="button rect A2" name="age" value="36"></input>
                        <label for="a36">36-64</label>

                        <input class="age" type="radio" id="a37" class="button rect A3" name="age" value="65"></input>
                        <label for="a37">65+</label>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.age -->

                <div class="ethnicity">
                    <p class="category">Ethnicity<span>*<span></p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" id="White" class="button rect E1" ></input>
                        <label for="White">White</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" id="Black" class="button rect E2" ></input>
                        <label for="Black">Black</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" id="Aboriginal" class="button rect E3" ></input>
                        <label for="Aboriginal">Aboriginal</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" id="Metis" class="button rect E4" ></input>
                        <label for="Metis">Metis</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" id="Asian" class="button rect E5" ></input>
                        <label for="Asian">Asian</label>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.ethnicity -->
            </section>

            <figure class="chart">
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <div class="info">
                        <p class="tooltipName"></p>
                        <p class="tooltipParty"></p> <p class="tooltipConstuency"></p>
                        <p class="tooltipEthnicity"></p> <p class="tooltipAge"></p>
                    </div><!-- /.info -->
                </div><!-- /.tooltip -->

                <div class="columns">
                </div><!-- /.columns -->


            </figure>

            <section class="others">
                <h2>There are <span class="number" id="count">56</span> MLAs that fit in your demographic</h2>
                <figcaption class="special">(Does not include the single vacant seat for the Pas or the Speaker.)</figcaption>
                    <div class="resetContainer">
                        <button id="reset">Try again</button>
                    </div><!-- /.reset -->
            </section>
        </section><!-- /.interactive -->
    </main>

    <div class="homescreen">
        <p class="install">Click to
            <span class="addContainer">
                <svg class="addIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="5.0 -10.0 100.0 135.0" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" height="100px" width="100px">
                    <path id="Share" d="M80.3,33.5V95H18.8V33.5h22.9l0,5.4H24.2v50.7h50.6V38.9H58.9l0-5.4H80.3z M34.7,25.8l12.9-12.9v46  c0,1.4,1.2,2.6,2.6,2.6c1.4,0,2.6-1.2,2.6-2.6v-46l12.9,12.9c0.8,0.8,2.2,0.8,3.1,0c0.8-0.8,0.8-2.2,0-3.1L51.6,5.6  c-0.8-0.8-2-0.8-2.7,0L31.6,22.8c-0.8,0.8-0.8,2.2,0,3.1C32.5,26.7,33.9,26.7,34.7,25.8z"/>
                    <text x="0.0" y="117.5" font-size="5.0" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial-Unicode, Arial, Sans-serif" fill="#000000">Created by Tom Walsh</text><text x="0.0" y="122.5" font-size="5.0" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial-Unicode, Arial, Sans-serif" fill="#000000">from the Noun Project</text></svg>
                </span> install our Legislature App on your phone</p>

                <p class="add">Then, tap the button <span class="plusContainer">
                    <svg class="plusIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="&#1057;&#1083;&#1086;&#1081;_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="5.0 -10.0 100.0 135.0" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path d="M70,17.5H30c-6.893,0-12.5,5.607-12.5,12.5v40c0,6.893,5.607,12.5,12.5,12.5h40c6.893,0,12.5-5.607,12.5-12.5V30  C82.5,23.107,76.893,17.5,70,17.5z M77.5,70c0,4.136-3.364,7.5-7.5,7.5H30c-4.136,0-7.5-3.364-7.5-7.5V30c0-4.136,3.364-7.5,7.5-7.5  h40c4.136,0,7.5,3.364,7.5,7.5V70z"/>
                        <path d="M67.5,47.5h-15v-15c0-1.381-1.119-2.5-2.5-2.5s-2.5,1.119-2.5,2.5v15h-15c-1.381,0-2.5,1.119-2.5,2.5s1.119,2.5,2.5,2.5h15  v15c0,1.381,1.119,2.5,2.5,2.5s2.5-1.119,2.5-2.5v-15h15c1.381,0,2.5-1.119,2.5-2.5S68.881,47.5,67.5,47.5z"/>
                        <text x="0.0" y="117.5" font-size="5.0" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial-Unicode, Arial, Sans-serif" fill="#000000">Created by Arthur Shlain</text><text x="0.0" y="122.5" font-size="5.0" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial-Unicode, Arial, Sans-serif" fill="#000000">from the Noun Project</text></svg>
                    </span> to "Add to Homescreen"</p>
                </div><!-- /.homescreen -->

                <footer>
                    <img src="assets/img/branding/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
                    <p class="new">Thanks for checking out the Brandon Sun's new legislature app. <span class="think">Let us know what you think.</span></p>
                    <!-- <p class="credits">Created by Graeme Bruce and Andrew Nguyen</p> -->
                    <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PiAW8Jx8lncnDfmua-D0aSJNkHsOhob9ffLI7BUcaP0/viewform?usp=send_form" target="_blank"><p class="feedback">Give us feedback</p></a>
                    <div class="crossContainer">
                        <svg class="cross" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="5.0 -10.0 100.0 135.0" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path d="M52.828,50l28.586-28.586c0.781-0.781,0.781-2.047,0-2.828c-0.78-0.781-2.048-0.781-2.828,0L50,47.172L21.414,18.586  c-0.78-0.781-2.048-0.781-2.828,0c-0.781,0.781-0.781,2.047,0,2.828L47.172,50L18.586,78.586c-0.781,0.781-0.781,2.047,0,2.828  C18.976,81.805,19.488,82,20,82s1.024-0.195,1.414-0.586L50,52.828l28.586,28.586C78.976,81.805,79.488,82,80,82  s1.024-0.195,1.414-0.586c0.781-0.781,0.781-2.047,0-2.828L52.828,50z"/>
                        </div>
                    </footer>

                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

## footer.scss

```
/*----------------------------------
FOOTER
----------------------------------*/
footer {
    background: $yellow;
    padding-bottom: 0.75%;
    // margin-top: 20px;
    // clear: both;
}

.logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 940px) {
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 680px) {
    .logo {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 415px) {
    .logo {
        position: relative;
        top: 12px;
        left: 5px;
    }
}

.new, .credits {
    @include serifLight;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    display: inline;
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 940px) {
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 680px) {
    .new {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .new {
        display: none;
    }
}

.feedbackContainer {
    display: inline;
}

.feedback {
    @include sansLightBlack;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    border: 1px solid $black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 6%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 6.5%;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 7%;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 7.5%;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 917px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 11.5%;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 885px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 9.5%;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 870px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 8.5%;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 855px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 7.5%;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 845px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 12.5%;
    }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 680px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 55%;
        padding: 18px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 415px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 54%;
        padding: 20px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 415px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 52%;
        padding: 18px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 375px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 18px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 350px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 46%;
        padding: 18px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .feedback {
        width: 45%;
        padding: 18px;
    }
}

.crossContainer {
    float: right;
    &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.cross {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid $black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    fill: $black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 917px) {
    .cross {
        display: none;
    }
}

span.think {
    color: $black;
}

/* Portrait tablet and small desktops */
@media (max-width: 845px) {
    span.think {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Andrew, look at the solution I provided. It should work. The other answers tell you to use `position: absolute`. You should be using `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your footer CSS

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, can you put it in a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the body margin to 0 somewhere, because it is not in your css code. Standard webkit (chrome) body has margin of 8px

```
body {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your footer, you'll want to add:

```
footer {
position: fixed; /* position: absolute puts to bottom, but moves on scroll */
bottom: 0;
width: 100%; /* if not already appearing 100% */
}
```

I also see that you're trying to comment some of your styles out at line 7 and 8 of your footer declaration in footer.scss by using `//` You should be using `/*` and `*/` instead.

And if you want the footer to always be positioned at the bottom, you may want to add a bottom padding the same height as the footer to either the body tag or the parent container of the page. This way the bottom footer won't cover up any content that goes to the bottom of the page. And make sure you remember to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the parent you're adding the bottom padding to.

Regarding the spacing issue you're referring to, I don't have `assets/css/style.css` to my disposal. But in footer.css, when I add:

```
body {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

I don't see any issues with spacing.

Here's a fiddle I made of your setup that also shows the sticky footer in action: http://jsfiddle.net/bpzco76j/

Comment: I hope it worked for you. Keep in mind that when you want something sticky, you need to use position: fixed. This will keep it in it's position even when scrolling. position: absolute stays within the position relative to the parent, so when scrolling it will move out of visibility.